# ChartJS: How to force redraw after hiding data items clicking on legend?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, label, legend

I've a ChartJS pie chart, where I draw the labels myself.
This works fine - until the legend comes into play.

```
const options = {      
   layout: {
      ...
   },
   plugins: {
      chartLineLabelPlugin: {
         ...
      },
      legend: {
         display: true
      },
   }
};
```

[image]

Using the legend, the user can click on labels and thus hide this single data item.
The pie chart is redrawn but the `afterDraw` function of other plugins is never called.

1. How can I force to redraw the chart in a way, that the `afterDraw` is called clicking on legend items?
2. How can I identify the hidden data items?

Comment: Please add a reproducable sample because when I click the legend and the chart redraws after draw gets called correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/mu5ad8n6/

Comment: Thanks - by your simple example I found the error and the solution: The "hidden" information isn't stored somewhere in the data structure of the chart, but in the "legend.legendItems"

Comment: Is this plugin chartLineLabelPlugin available anywhere?

Comment: Currently not - I shy away from the effort of publishing it with all documentation on github